# CKEditor preventing PrintArea.js working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, printing, ckeditor

I have two divs. In one div (the "show" div) is some html. Hidden in front of that div is a form to edit that div with a CKEditor instance. I have a button to toggle between the two of them hiding one while revealing the other.

Now, I have a print button that fires PrintArea.js. It's supposed to print the div with the class 'printarea' from the "show" div and it does this very reliably when there is no CKEditor instance on the page.

The CKEditor instance is definitely the problem because when I remove that part of the form it's fine.

The problem code on PrintArea.js is this:

```
.filter(function(){ // this filter contributed by "mindinquiring"
                var media = $(this).attr("media");
                return (media.toLowerCase() == "all" || media.toLowerCase() == "print")
```

The error message in dev tools is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError:Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading PrintArea to 2.2.2 fixed the problem. I do not know how unfortunately.